# Wifi and Bluetooth won't connect without reboot

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth

I have a Pixel 3XL. Recently, Bluetooth will sometimes see devices, but won't be able to connect. Wifi get stuck searching for networks.

Turning WiFi or Bluetooth off and on does not solve the problems. A reboot will fix the problems. Is there a more permanent fix?

Android version 12
Build SP1A.210812.016.C2